# Export or download c3 chart to pdf using canvas and jspdf

Tags: jquery, export, jspdf, c3

I' m developing a c3 chart for my website. I'm trying to download c3 svg chart as pdf. I successfully did that but there is problem in pdf, I'm getting axis value double. In website it is coming in single but in pdf It is coming double.
Please help I'm sharing my code and screen shots . If someone knows this then please have a look once.

```
$(function () {
var doc = new jsPDF();
$('#mdt').click(function () {
canvg('canvas', $("#chart05").html().trim());
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 15, 40, 180, 60);
doc.save('sample.pdf');
});
});

    <canvas id="canvas3" style="display: none"></canvas>
```

Screen shot 
[image: Screen shot of pdf]

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you resolve this problem?